# How to change the text value after/while styling the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, styling

I have a dataframe and I have styled using the following code but wherever the condition met i.e. red color. I want to replace the value to 0. I have used applymap(function, subset=['col1','col2']) which returns styled dataframe but I need to replace the values too.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def applystyle(value):
    if float(value) < 1.0:
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s; text:0;' % color

data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
data.style.applymap(applystyle, subset=['C','A'])
```

[image]

Comment: So is not possible set `0` before using styling? Because not sure after is possible

Comment: yeah it's based on the value I am apply color of the cell after wards it's giving me Styler attribute error.

Comment: df.style.applymap(function, subset=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])

function takes value argument I am checking the condition then returning return 'background-color: %s; ' % color

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, we can replace value using data attribute in style object

```
#Store the style object in a variable
s=data.style.applymap(applystyle, subset=['C','A'])

#Check and replace the negative value
column=['A','C']
for cols in column:
    s.data[cols]=s.data[cols].apply(change_value)
s  # s will provide the dataframe with style and and modified data   

def change_value(data):
    if data<1.0:
       data=0
return data
```